# running mvn exec in the background of remote server

Tags: java, linux, maven, amazon-ec2

Trying to run `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass.`

that run a long process (could take up to 16 hours) on EC2 but whenever I lose connection with the remote server, the process stopped. I was wondering if I can run this in the background that doesn't affect my connection with EC2 remote server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you just running it on the command line? You can use nohup (http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/)

```
nohup mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass &
```

Comment: Dude, you are awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. I wish I can buy you a cup of coffee :)

Comment: @MagedMakled No problem, mark my answer correct and we'll call it even :)

Comment: @KharyMendez I am running this command on server from local system(connecting server using ssh) but if i close my local system terminal then this process also exits.

But i donot want this exit

Comment: @ankit Does nohup not solve this issue for you?  You can also look into using tmux or screen on your local system. Basically you would start a tmux session, ssh to the remote server to start your command, then detach from your tmux session.

Comment: @KharyMendez This work in background but if i stay my terminal open.